# JavaScript access string chars as array

Tags: javascript

Is it ok to do this:

```
var myString="Hello!";
alert(myString[0]); // shows "H" in an alert window
```

Or should it be done with either charAt(0) or substr(0,1)?
By "is it ok" I mean will it work on most browsers, is there a best practice recommandation that says otherwise etc.

Thank you.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Using `charAt` is probably the best idea since it conveys the intent of your code most accurately. Calling `substr` for a single character is definitely an overkill.

```
alert(myString.charAt(0));
```

Comment: This approach fails if the first character in the string is represented by multiple UTF8 code points (emoji, combining characters, etc).

Answer (score 54):

Accessing characters as numeric properties of a string is [non-standard prior to ECMAScript 5 and doesn't work in all browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#section_5) (for example, it doesn't work in IE 6 or 7). You should use `myString.charAt(0)` instead when your code has to work in non-ECMAScript 5 environments. Alternatively, if you're going to be accessing a lot of characters in the string then you can turn a string into an array of characters using its `split()` method:

```
var myString = "Hello!";
var strChars = myString.split("");
alert(strChars[0]);
```

Comment: just to add a link/reference for the non-standard comment, see (under Character access): https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

Comment: @davin: Thanks. I've now linked to that section in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, Tim. Just wanted to add that it does work in IE8. Not sure about others.

Comment: @Francisc: Ah, OK, thanks. I tested on IE 7. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Francisc: Are you sure accessing characters as numeric properties of a string works in IE 8? It doesn't seem to.

Comment: Hey! Yup: `var myStr="JavaScript";alert(myStr[4]);` will show "S". Just gave it another test.

Comment: Though bear in mind that that will blow up memory usage significantly.

Comment: @gsnedders: I assume you're referring to the suggestion of using `split()`? Unless you're keeping lots of large arrays hanging around I can't see that being much of an issue in most situations.

Comment: Bizarrely, just earlier today I had reason to check whether IE8 supports bracket notation on strings, and then *completely independently* from that, came across this answer: Yes, IE8 supports bracket notation on strings. IE6 and IE7 are finally irrelevant here in 2018. :-)

Answer (score 18):

2018 answer: **Yes it is OK** to access strings like arrays.

The syntax is clear and concise. IE6 and IE7 are long gone. I see no reason not to use it.

Comment: However: don't get confused into thinking you can use all the Array methods, like `reverse` and `pop`, on Strings.

Answer (score 7):

In ES6 we can use destructuring since a string can be treated as an array:

```
const [...rest] = 'Hello!';

console.log(rest)
> Array ["H", "e", "l", "l", "o", "!"]

console.log(rest[0])
> "H"
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer, as it's the only method which correctly handles characters that cannot be represented by a single UTF8 code point (combining characters, emoji, etc).

Comment: You don't need ES6 to do that. rest = Array.prototype.slice.call("Hello!") will return the same thing and it works in old browsers.