# How do I split a string into an array of characters?

Tags: javascript, string

```
var s = "overpopulation";
var ar = [];
ar = s.split();
alert(ar);
```

I want to string.split a word into array of characters.

The above code doesn't seem to work - it returns  "overpopulation"  as Object..

How do i split it into array of characters, if original string doesn't contain commas and whitespace?

Comment: *related*: [JavaScript access string chars as array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051385/javascript-access-string-chars-as-array)

Comment: ar is an array variable but alert() takes string variables.  :)

Answer (score 282, accepted):

You can split on an empty string:

```
var chars = "overpopulation".split('');
```

---

If you just want to access a string in an array-like fashion, you can do that without `split`:

```
var s = "overpopulation";
for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    console.log(s.charAt(i));
}
```

---

You can also access each character with its index using normal array syntax. Note, however, that strings are immutable, which means you can't *set* the value of a character using this method, and that it isn't supported by IE7 (if that still matters to you).

```
var s = "overpopulation";

console.log(s[3]); // logs 'r'
```

Comment: You can also access the string's characters in an array like fashion like so: `mystr = "apples"; mystr[0]; // a`

Comment: This does NOT work for emojis
"".length  #=> 1
"".chars   #=> [""]

Comment: This does not consider wide characters.

Comment: This will not handle strings like this: `"⬆️⬆️⬇️⬇️⬅️➡️⬅️➡️️️"`.

However, `[..."⬆️⬆️⬇️⬇️⬅️➡️⬅️➡️️️"]` and `Array.from("⬆️⬆️⬇️⬇️⬅️➡️⬅️➡️️️")` also won't handle this string correctly. To correctly handle this string you'll need to use a library like this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grapheme-splitter

Answer (score 185):

Old question but I should warn:

## Do NOT use `.split('')`

You'll get weird results with **non-BMP** (non-Basic-Multilingual-Plane) character sets.

Reason is that methods like `.split()` and `.charCodeAt()` only respect the characters with a code point below 65536; bec. higher code points are represented by **a pair** of (lower valued) "**surrogate**" pseudo-characters.

```
''.length     // —> 6
''.split('')  // —> ["�", "�", "�", "�", "�", "�"]

''.length      // —> 2
''.split('')   // —> ["�", "�"]
```

### Use ES2015 (ES6) features where possible:

Using the **spread** operator:

```
let arr = [...str];
```

Or `Array.from`

```
let arr = Array.from(str);
```

Or `split` with the new `u` RegExp flag:

```
let arr = str.split(/(?!$)/u);
```

Examples:

```
[...'']        // —> ["", "", ""]
[...'']     // —> ["", "", ""]
```

### For ES5, options are limited:

I came up with this function that internally uses [MDN example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) to get the correct code point of each character.

```js
function stringToArray() {
  var i = 0,
    arr = [],
    codePoint;
  while (!isNaN(codePoint = knownCharCodeAt(str, i))) {
    arr.push(String.fromCodePoint(codePoint));
    i++;
  }
  return arr;
}
```

This requires [`knownCharCodeAt()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt#Fixing_charCodeAt()_to_handle_non-Basic-Multilingual-Plane_characters_if_their_presence_earlier_in_the_string_is_known) and for some browsers; a `String.fromCodePoint()` polyfill.

```js
if (!String.fromCodePoint) {
// ES6 Unicode Shims 0.1 , © 2012 Steven Levithan , MIT License
    String.fromCodePoint = function fromCodePoint () {
        var chars = [], point, offset, units, i;
        for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i) {
            point = arguments[i];
            offset = point - 0x10000;
            units = point > 0xFFFF ? [0xD800 + (offset >> 10), 0xDC00 + (offset & 0x3FF)] : [point];
            chars.push(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, units));
        }
        return chars.join("");
    }
}
```

Examples:

```js
stringToArray('')     // —> ["", "", ""]
stringToArray('')  // —> ["", "", ""]
```

---

**Note**: `str[index]` (ES5) and `str.charAt(index)` will also return weird results with non-BMP charsets. e.g. `''.charAt(0)` returns `"�"`.

UPDATE: Read this [nice article](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode) about JS and unicode.

Comment: thanks for teaching me how to make my regexps emoji-friendly, I never knew I needed that 'till now

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: What if you want to use ES6 but split words at a `'  '`, and not every char?

Comment: @AlfaBravo  same.

Comment: Note that this solution splits some emoji such as ️‍, and splits combining diacritics mark from characters

Answer (score 27):

`.split('')` splits emojis in half.

[Onur's solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38901550) work for some emojis, but can't handle more complex languages or combined emojis.

Consider this emoji being ruined:

```
[..."️‍"] // returns ["", "️", "‍", ""]  instead of ["️‍"]
```

Also consider this Hindi text `अनुच्छेद` which is split like this:

```
[..."अनुच्छेद"]  // returns   ["अ", "न", "ु", "च", "्", "छ", "े", "द"]
```

but should in fact be split like this:

```
["अ","नु","च्","छे","द"]
```

This happens because some of the characters are combining marks (think diacritics/accents in European languages).

You can use the [grapheme-splitter](https://github.com/orling/grapheme-splitter) library for this:

It does proper standards-based letter split in all the hundreds of exotic edge-cases - yes, there are that many.

Comment: ["अ", "न", "ु", "च", "्", "छ", "े", "द"] is that right in the sense of the Hindi language, it's the right split

Answer (score 20):

It's as simple as:

```
s.split("");
```

The delimiter is an empty string, hence it will break up between each single character.

Comment: Does not consider wide characters.

Answer (score 11):

The split() method in javascript accepts two parameters: a separator and a limit.
The separator specifies the character to use for splitting the string. If you don't specify a separator, the entire string is returned, non-separated. But, if you specify the empty string as a separator, the string is split between each character.

Therefore:

```
s.split('')
```

will have the effect you seek.

More information [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

Answer (score 7):

A string in Javascript is already a character array.

You can simply access any character in the array as you would any other array.

```
var s = "overpopulation";
alert(s[0]) // alerts o.
```

**UPDATE**

As is pointed out in the comments below, the above method for accessing a character in a string is part of ECMAScript 5 which certain browsers may not conform to.

An alternative method you can use is `charAt(index)`.

```
var s = "overpopulation";
    alert(s.charAt(0)) // alerts o.
```

Comment: This does not work in all browsers though (not in some versions of IE: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#section_5.

Comment: Thanks Felix. I've updated my answer to include charAt as defined pre ECMAScript 5.

Answer (score 6):

To support emojis use this

```
('Dragon ').split(/(?!$)/u);
```

`=> ['D', 'r', 'a', 'g', 'o', 'n', ' ', '']`

Comment: It breaks with `'Flag ️‍'.split(/(?!$)/u)` => `['F', 'l', 'a', 'g', ' ', '', '️', '‍', '']`

Answer (score 5):

You can use the regular expression `/(?!$)/`:

```
"overpopulation".split(/(?!$)/)
```

The negative look-ahead assertion `(?!$)` will match right in front of every character.