# Split string into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

In JS if you would like to split user entry into an array what is the best way of going about it?

For example:

```
entry = prompt("Enter your name")

for (i=0; i<entry.length; i++)
{
entryArray[i] = entry.charAt([i]);
}

// entryArray=['j', 'e', 'a', 'n', 's', 'y'] after loop
```

Perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way - would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Use the [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method. When specifying an empty string as the separator, the `split()` method will return an array with one element per character.

```
entry = prompt("Enter your name")
entryArray = entry.split("");
```

Comment: Don't use `.split('')`. Pls see http://stackoverflow.com/a/38901550/112731

Answer (score 17):

## ES6 :

```
const array = [...entry]; // entry="i am" => array=["i"," ","a","m"]
```

Answer (score 12):

use `var array = entry.split("");`

Answer (score 10):

Do you care for non-English names? If so, all of the presented solutions (.split(''), [...str], Array.from(str), etc.) may give bad results, depending on language:

```
"प्रणव मुखर्जी".split("") // the current president of India, Pranab Mukherjee
// returns ["प", "्", "र", "ण", "व", " ", "म", "ु", "ख", "र", "्", "ज", "ी"]
// but should return ["प्", "र", "ण", "व", " ", "मु", "ख", "र्", "जी"]
```

Consider using the grapheme-splitter library for a clean standards-based split:
https://github.com/orling/grapheme-splitter

Answer (score 5):

```
var foo = 'somestring';
```

---

```
// bad example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484670/how-do-i-split-a-string-into-an-array-of-characters/38901550#38901550

var arr = foo.split(''); 
console.log(arr); // ["s", "o", "m", "e", "s", "t", "r", "i", "n", "g"]
```

---

```
// good example
var arr = Array.from(foo);
console.log(arr); // ["s", "o", "m", "e", "s", "t", "r", "i", "n", "g"]
```

---

```
// best
var arr = [...foo]
console.log(arr); // ["s", "o", "m", "e", "s", "t", "r", "i", "n", "g"]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `split` method:

```
entry = prompt("Enter your name");
entryArray = entry.split("");
```

Refer [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

`var entryArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(entry)`

Comment: See [http://jsperf.com/string-to-array-of-characters](http://jsperf.com/string-to-array-of-characters).

Answer (score 3):

...and also for those who like literature in CS.

```
array = Array.from(entry);
```

Answer (score 2):

ES6 is quite powerful in iterating through objects (strings, Array, Map, Set).
Let's use a Spread Operator to solve this.

```
entry = prompt("Enter your name");
var count = [...entry];
console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way:

```
let entry = prompt("Enter your name") 
let entryArray = entry.split('')
console.log(entryArray)
```

here is fiddle
  https://jsfiddle.net/swapanil/Lp1arvqc/17/