# Javascript's equivalent of Python's list()

Tags: javascript, python, list, function

Similar to or like the function:

```
list("String")
'''
return: ['S','t','r','i','n','g']
'''
```

Is there a Javascript equivalent of the function?

Comment: You mean you want char array? Use split function eg: "String".split('')

Comment: For latest browser use `Array.from`

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI I don't think it's a duplicate, because [`list()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list) has more uses in Python than getting character arrays. It's a general purpose converter from iterable types to list types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest equivalent in all cases of what is passed to [`list()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list) would be using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) from ES6. For older versions of JavaScript, you can use `string.split('')` for a character array. Note that `.split('')` [won't work with characters that use surrogate pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38901550/5743988).

```js
function list(iterable) {
  return [...iterable];  
}

console.log(list('String'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method with empty string separator as an argument which converts a string into a character array.

```
"String".split('')
```

```js
console.log(
  "String".split('')
)
```

---

For latest browsers, use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) method or [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

```
// Using Array.from 
var arr = Array.from("String")

// Using spread syntax 
var arr = [..."String"]
```

```js
console.log(
  Array.from("String")
)

console.log(
  [..."String"]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "String"    
str.split('');
```

That should do it

Answer (score 0):

Use the split method, `"Hello world!".split('')`.

```js
console.log(
  "Hello world!".split('')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a String into an Array with each element being a character of the string, you can use `String.prototype.split()`:

```
"String".split('') //['S', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g']
```