# how to store the string "1+2+3" as an array like ["1","+","2","+","3"] in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split, splice

```js
var numbers = "3+3/2";

console.log(numbers);

var numArr = numbers.split(" ");
console.log(numArr);
numArr.splice(1, 3, '1');
console.log(numArr);
numbers = numArr.toString();

console.log(numbers);
```

```
var numbers = "3+3/2";

console.log(numbers);

var numArr = numbers.split(" ");
console.log(numArr);
numArr.splice(1, 3, '1');
console.log(numArr);
numbers = numArr.toString();

console.log(numbers);
```

> I am trying to convert the whole string into an array.
> Then use the splice to edit the numArr
> Then change the original string, numbers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I split a string into an array of characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484670/how-do-i-split-a-string-into-an-array-of-characters). See the second answer especially.

Comment: You can just use spread. `let strs = [..."3+3/2"]`

Comment: `"3+3/2".split("")` without the space between quotes.

Comment: @kosmos - apparently, that's not recommended: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38901550/8402369 ...but it may be fine if no special chars are used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split the string with nonnumber characters.

```js
var numbers = "3+3/2",
    parts = numbers.split(/(\D+)/);

console.log(parts);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a regular expression to either match numbers or non-space, non-digit characters:

```js
var numbers = "3+3/2";
console.log(
  numbers.match(/\d+|[^\s\d]+/g)
);
```