# Use String functions on an element while using map() on array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I am trying to do the following.

```js
strs = ["one", "two"];
let sorted_str = strs.map((s) => [s.sort(), s]);
```

Essentially, what I am trying to do is create a new array of arrays, where this new array is like `[sorted string from first array, original string from first array]`

However, it looks like the `.sort()` method is not valid here.

I even tried making it

```js
let sorted_str = strs.map((s) => [s.toString().sort(), s]);
```

to force a String and make sure it has a `sort()` method possible, but to no avail.

The error is `TypeError: s.toString(...).sort is not a function`.

Any way I can get this to work or any simple workaround will be appreciated.

Comment: Sort is an array method. Your trying to use it on a string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get an array of characters, sort it and get a string back.

```js
const
    strs = ["one", "two"],
    sorted_str = strs.map((s) => [Array.from(s).sort().join(''), s]);

console.log(sorted_str);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert to array, then apply the sort method, and then join to a string again, try this:

```js
strs = ["one", "two"];
let sorted_str = strs.map((s) => [s.split('').sort().join(''), s])

console.log(sorted_str);
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of using `split()`. [do not use split()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38901550/10727157)

```js
strs = ["one", "two"];
let sorted_str = strs.map((s) => [[...s].sort().join(''), s]);

console.log(sorted_str)
```

Comment: Hmm nice solution. Thanks! Nina's answer above with `Array.from()` also sounds good.

Answer (score 1):

The String class does not have a `.sort()` method. The array class does, though! So you can convert the string to an array, sort that, and then convert the sorted array back to a string. That would look something like

```
s.split("").sort().join("")
```

Answer (score 1):

The `sort()` method needs an array as input, but if you call it in the callback function passed to a `map()` you are calling it on a single string.

I'm not 100% sure that I understood the desired output, anyway here is my solution.

Let's start with an array of Strings that we want to sort.

```js
const items = ['cat', 'dog', 'elephant', 'bee', 'ant'];
```

Now in order to sort it without mutating it we can do:

```js
const sortedItems = [...items].sort();
```

Now we have two arrays, the original one, and another one with the sorted strings.

We can use `map()` to loop over the original array and to create the array that you need. The `index` parameter in the callback function can be used to retrieve the item in the sorted array.

```js
const newItems = items.map((item, index) => {
  return [sortedItems[index], item];
});
```

Now if I understood correctly we have what you needed:

```js
[
  ['ant', 'cat'], // 'ant' (from the sorted array), 'cat' (from the original)
  ['bee', 'dog'],  // same thing
  ['cat', 'elephant'], // etc.
  ['dog', 'bee'],
  ['elephant', 'ant']
]
```

If you want you can put everything together in one function:

```js
const sortingMethod = (items) => {
  const sortedItems = [...items].sort();
  return items.map((item, index) => {
    return [sortedItems[index], item];
  });
}
```

That you can call like this:

```js
const newElements = sortingMethod(['cat', 'dog', 'elephant', 'bee', 'ant']);
console.log(newElements);
```