# AJAX JQuery string result broken down by character

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    url: '@Url.Action("UpdateMS")' + "?MAC=" + $('#MAC').val() + "&Serial=" + $('#Serial').val() + "&I_ID=" + $('#I_ID').val(),
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        $("#Serial_Number").val("");
        $("#MAC_Address").val("");
        $("#Message").text(data);
        alert(data[0]);
        if (data[0] == 'D') {                        
            $("#PartOne").css("display", "inline");
            $("#PartTwo").css("display", "none");
            $("#MACSerial").val("");
            $("#MACSerial").focus();
        }
    }
});
```

`data` is a JSON string having the value `Device Updated`.

Here is the issue:

On Google Chrome and the like works like a charm.

`data[0]` has a value of `"D"`  (Ie. the first character in a string array).

Except on a stinky old mobile device it reports value `undefined` when i run my test alert!

`data` itself produces the proper string `"Device Updated"` correctly on all browsers.

Any ideas??  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `data.charAt(0)`. Your way of accessing a string is not supported by all browsers.

Check this [JavaScript access string chars as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051385/javascript-access-string-chars-as-array) out, there's explanation as to why in the answers.

Comment: Also, if your MAC, Serial, and I_ID are all part of the same form, you can use the jQuery .serialize() function and the data property of jQuery .ajax() to send the information in a much more readable format.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help!  Now i can have my morning Oats!