# javascript string assignment by index number quirk

Tags: javascript

```
a="12345"
a[2]=3
a[2]='9'
console.log(a) //=> "12345"
```

What is going on?? This quirk caused me 1 hour painful debugging. How to avoid this in a sensible way?

Comment: same here it took half an hour....

Comment: How could `a[2]=3` clarify, whether the behaviour is like expected or not? The outcome seems to be the same in both cases. Does it matter that `3` is not a string literal, but `'9'` is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot use brackets to rewrite individual characters of the string; only 'getter' (i.e. read) access is available. Quoting the doc ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Character_access)):

> For character access using bracket notation, attempting to delete or
>   assign a value to these properties will not succeed. The properties
>   involved are neither writable nor configurable.

That's for "what's going on" part of the question. And for "how to replace" part there's a useful snippet (taken from [an answer written long, long ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1431113/1229023)):

```
String.prototype.replaceAt = function(index, char) {
    return this.slice(0, index) + char + this.slice(index+char.length);
}
```

You may use as it is (biting the bullet of extending the JS native object) - or inject this code as a method in some utility object (obviously it should be rewritten a bit, taking the source string as its first param and working with it instead of `this`).

Answer (score 4):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051385/javascript-access-string-chars-as-array), this is not supported among all browsers.

If your strings aren't too long, you can do this relatively easy like that:

```
var a="12345";
a = a.split("");
a[2]='9';
a = a.join("");
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var letters = a.split('');
letters[2] = 3;
letters[2] = 9;
console.log(letters.join(''));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XWwKz/

Cheers